# Why does this example of async code lead to a memory leak (Task completes succesfully, but never gets garbage collected)

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks

We have an application that always grows in the amount of memory used. I have debugged this and found a memory leak, but cannot discover what is actually wrong with the code itself. I have used the "Make Object Id"-approach from [this article](https://michaelscodingspot.com/find-fix-and-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c-net-8-best-practices/) to verify that the objects still exist long after the Razor page that generated them has disappeared.

This is the simplified code to illustrate:

```
//this is the only four lines of code in my Console app
await AsyncStuffProcessor.DoAsyncStuff();

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();

//and these are the classes
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public bool AsyncResult { get; set; }
}

public static class AsyncStuffProcessor
{

    public static async Task<MyClass> DoAsyncStuff()
    {
        var model = new MyClass();
        //we set some properties on the model class
        model.Name = "some kind of name";
        model.TypeId = 13;

        //and pass the model to the ExecuteAsync method, which will perform async work based on values in the model class
        var t1 = ExecuteAsync(model);
        var t2 = ExecuteSomethingElseAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"T1: {t1.Id}");
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

        return model;
    }

    private static async Task ExecuteAsync(MyClass model)
    {
        //performs some async tasks, return when done,
        //set a property in my model to the right value depending on the result
        var result = await Task.Run<bool>(async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); return true; });

        if (result)
            model.AsyncResult = result;
    }

    private static Task ExecuteSomethingElseAsync()
    {
        //do some other async stuff
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

I place a breakpoint in my method `DoAsyncStuff` and use "Make Object ID" to name my reference to `t1` as $1.
Printing $1 in the Immediate Windows in Visual Studio after the last GC.Collect() will still print my Task. The t1 still exists, even after forcing Garbage Collection.

Also, the ID of the t1 task always remains the same. If I execute my `DoAsyncStuff()` method in a loop, I would create hundreds of new Tasks named t1. Using the immediate window, I see that $1 is always the first task I created and this keeps on existing.

Why is this, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: I think you might have oversimplified this example. We can't take this code and reproduce the problem because types and methods that your code depends on are missing.

Comment: This wouldn't even compile since you are returning something in the first method. We really need a [mre] here.

Comment: I have a working Console app to demonstrate this. Let me just post the code of that. Editing question now.

Comment: Question edited with working example to demonstrate.

Comment: `Using the immediate window, I see that $1 is always the first task I created and this keeps on existing.` - This part isn't surprising. `$1` will always refer to the first task.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I agree that it seems logical, but shouldn't that variable return null in the immediate window after my `DoAsyncStuff()` method has completed and the reference to t1 is disposed?

Comment: @StevenLemmens: Probably has something to do with the debugger extending object lifetimes. Try to repro using a weak reference, building in Release, and running it outside VS.